# Sort Dates without year

Tags: c#

I have a list of objects which have a string property called date. The objects are populated from an SQL database. The date property contains the month and day of the object (NO YEAR) in the format of MM-DD. I want to be able to organize these in a way so that the object with next date closest to the current date is at the top of the list.

The reason why I am not using the DateTime object or Date datatype in MySQL is because I am trying to prevent updating the year every time the date has passed within the year. I just want to be able to see if the date is coming or has passed (obviously if the date has passed, it would be towards the bottom of the list).

I know this way of thinking may not be ideal and am open to other suggestions in this matter.

EDIT:

Here's some more information with exact structure of what I am using:

Sample Database Info:

```
DomainName       RenewDate       ClientName

mydomain.com     02-01           John Doe
thisdomain.com   08-30           Tim Jones
thatdomain.com   10-10           Jane Smith
```

Objects:

```
internal class Domain
{
    private string name;
    private string renewDate;
    private string client;

/* Getters, Setters, Constructors, & Other Methods */
}
```

Once the objects are created, they are stored in a list and I want to sort them based on the next closest to the current day. For example if it was sorted today the order of the objects would be:

- thatdomain.com | 10-10 | Jane Smith
- mydomain.com | 02-01 | John Doe
- thisdomain.com | 08-30 | Tim Jones

The point of this in the end is to populate a table with this information so I know which domain renewal dates are approaching so I can send the client an invoice manually. I did not think it was necessary to add the year as I would have to update it every time the exact date passed.

Again, I know this is probably not the most efficient way to go about this and am open to all suggestions for a better implementation, this is just my though process at the moment.

Comment: Some sample data and expected results would be helpful.

Comment: Do you have a rule to which year such a "MM-DD" belongs to?

Comment: This sounds like an **[XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)**

Comment: "Next date closest to the current date" is this future dates or future and past dates closest to the current date? Because yesterday is closer than Saturday but can't think of a use where it would be needed

Comment: I think I understand what Dr_Berry721 is trying to solve. He has something like a TODO list on a particular date recurring every year. Sort of like recurring payments on a particular date which he needs sorted. The 'next-due-date' is what he wants at the head of a circular list. The problem is solved by `1. Sort the list in ascending order (2) Rotate the list (Skip/Take) to the nearest next date`

Comment: Please see the edited post for more information on the current code structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a bit of code that you can modify to your problem. However this can be made more general (and also a lot more safer | production ready).

```
    class FancyDate
    {
        public int Month { get; set; }
        public int Day { get; set; }

        public FancyDate(string fancyDate)
        {
            var split = fancyDate.Split('-');
            Month = Int32.Parse(split[0]);
            Day = Int32.Parse(split[1]);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Month:D2}-{Day:D2}";
        }
    }

    class ClientRenewal
    {
        public string ClientName { get; set; }
        public FancyDate RenewalDate { get; set; } 
        public string DomainName { get; set; }

        public class ClientRenewalComparer : IComparer<ClientRenewal>
        {
            public int Compare(ClientRenewal x, ClientRenewal y)
            {
                if (x != null && y != null)
                    return String.Compare(x.RenewalDate.ToString(), y.RenewalDate.ToString(), StringComparison.Ordinal);
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            }
        }

        public ClientRenewal(string clientName, string renewalDate, string domainName)
        {
            this.ClientName = clientName;
            this.RenewalDate = new FancyDate(renewalDate);
            this.DomainName = domainName;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{DomainName} - {RenewalDate} - {ClientName}";
        }
    }
    class ClientRenewalList
    {
        private List<ClientRenewal> theClientList;

        public ClientRenewalList(List<ClientRenewal> list)
        {
            list.Sort(new ClientRenewal.ClientRenewalComparer());
            theClientList = new List<ClientRenewal>();
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                theClientList.Add(item);
            }
        }

        private List<ClientRenewal> RotateListForCurrentDate()
        {
            // Bit of indirection to aid testing
            return RotateListForDate(DateTime.Now);
        }

        public List<ClientRenewal> RotateListForDate(DateTime dateTime)
        {
            var month = dateTime.Month;
            var day = dateTime.Day;
            int i = 0;
            while (i < theClientList.Count)
            {
                if (theClientList[i].RenewalDate.Month < month)
                {
                    i++;
                    continue;
                }
                if (theClientList[i].RenewalDate.Month == month)
                {
                    while (theClientList[i].RenewalDate.Day < day)
                    {
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                if (theClientList[i].RenewalDate.Month > month) break;
                if (theClientList[i].RenewalDate.Month >= month && theClientList[i].RenewalDate.Day >= day) break;
            }
            return theClientList.Skip(i).Concat(theClientList.Take(i)).ToList();
        }

        public List<ClientRenewal> GetListForDisplay()
        {
            return RotateListForCurrentDate();
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //mydomain.com     02 - 01           John Doe
        //thisdomain.com   08 - 30           Tim Jones
        //thatdomain.com   10 - 10           Jane Smith
        var listOfClientRenewal = new List<ClientRenewal>()
        {
            new ClientRenewal("John Doe", "02-01", "mydomain.com"),
            new ClientRenewal("Tim Jones", "08-30", "thisdomain.com"),
            new ClientRenewal("Jane Smith", "10-10", "thatdomain.com")
        };
        var list = new ClientRenewalList(listOfClientRenewal).GetListForDisplay();
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
```

And here's the output:

[image: Output]

Comment: I like the idea of a FancyDate object as I could store that object within the Domain class. My question however would be how could I sort a list of domain objects based on the FancyDate object instead of a List of string dates?

Comment: well I was working on that as you posted. Will post the final solution and the sorted list output. Check it out!

Comment: Awesome! This is perfect and functioning, thanks a ton!

Comment: @Dr_Berry721 yw np! Glad to help! Just a word of caution, I would test around `RotateListForDate()` before using this in production. Also `Int32.Parse()` is not as good as `Int32.TryParse()` for safer parsing but if this is your toy-app to do something then enjoy the code!

Answer (score 0):

If you read them in as strings from the database then you could try this:

```
List<string> dates = GetDates(); //returns dates in form MM-DD from db
dates = dates.OrderBy(x=int.Parse(x.Split('-')[0])
.ThenBy(x=>int.Parse(x.Split('-')[1])
.ToList();

 List<string> oldDates = new List<string>();
 List<string> futureDates = new List<string>();
foreach(var date in dates)
{
    string[] splitDate = date.Split('-');
    int month = int.Parse(splitDate[0]);
    int day = int.Parse(splitDate[1]);
    if(month < DateTime.Today.Month)
       oldDates.Add(date);
    else if(month == DateTime.Today.Month)
    {
        if(day < DateTime.Today.Day)
            oldDates.Add(date);
        else
            futureDates.Add(date)(
    }
    else
        futureDates.Add(date);

     dates = futureDates.AddRange(oldDates);
}
```

I'm on mobile SO so please format if you can :)

Answer (score 0):

You could add these three properties to your class, and then just order by that?

```
    internal class Domain
    {
        private string name;
        private string renewDate;
        private string client;

        /* Getters, Setters, Constructors, & Other Methods */

        public int LastRenewalDateMonth => int.Parse(renewDate.Split('-')[0]);
        public int LastRenewalDateDay => int.Parse(renewDate.Split('-')[1]);
        public DateTime LastRenewalDate => new DateTime(1901, LastRenewalDateMonth, LastRenewalDateDay);
    }
```

You don't care about the year, like you say.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements correctly, the following should be sufficient:

```
List<string> dates = new List<string>() { "02-01", "08-30", "10-10" };

CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
var sorted = dates.Select(s => DateTime.ParseExact(s, "MM-dd", ci))
                  .OrderBy(d => d);
var customSorted = sorted.SkipWhile(d => d <= DateTime.Today)
                         .Concat(sorted.TakeWhile(d => d <= DateTime.Today));

// In case you want them back as strings, otherwise, ignore the
// following line and add a `.ToList()` to the above line.
var customSortedStrings = customSorted.Select(d => d.ToString("MM-dd")).ToList();

foreach (string s in customSortedStrings)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

**Output:**

```
10-10
02-01
08-30
```